# how to connect android app to azure virtual machine's database

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, azure, xamarin

Now I have created azure virtual machine with SQL Server 2012 SP2 Standard. I have checked Application server and web server (IIS) for server role, and installed SQL Server Management Studio. So if I create new database with the Management Studio, the database is saved on azure cloud. Is that right? 
Now I want to connect my android application to the database so that i can save customer login information to the database. How can i do that? Do I have to deploy my application on virtual machine? I can't actually get an idea of how android application work with azure virtual machine. Can you guys explain in detail for me?

and I am currently using android studio for developments but is it better to use visual studio with xamarin if i am using azure cloud service?

Answer (score 1):

@KisungTae, I don't think it's a good solution to connect android app to the SQL Server hosted on Azure VM.

On Azure, the recommended solution is that create an Azure Mobile App for Android App to connect Azure SQL Database (not SQL Server on VM) as below.

Android App <---> [Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/) <---> [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/)

And whether using Android Studio or Visual Studio with/without Xamarin for developments, it just depend on your preferences and programming languages you used.

Hope it helps.